# How to disable Webkit Notifications?

Tags: html, webkit, html5-notifications

Is there a way I can give a user the option of disabling webkitNotifications?  If I call `requestPermission()` a second time, it does not prompt the user.

Answer (score 0):

I just ask for the permissions once, then I let the user configure whether he wants to receive notifications from a configuration panel.

You can store this option in a database on the server or client-side with `localStorage`.

### Display notification

```
if (notificationsEnabled) {
    var notification = new window.Notification("Hello");
}
```

### Restore setting on load

```
$(function () {
    notificationsEnabled = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notificationsEnabled') || false);
    $('#notificationsEnabled').prop('checked', notificationsEnabled);

    if (!window.Notification) {
        $('#notificationsEnabled').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

### Settings

```
<label>
    <input id="notificationsEnabled" name="notificationsEnabled" type="checkbox">
    Enable notifications
</label>
```

## Handle onchange events on the checkbox

```
$('#notificationsEnabled').on('change', function() {
    notificationsEnabled = !notificationsEnabled;
    localStorage.setItem('notificationsEnabled', notificationsEnabled);
    if (notificationsEnabled && window.Notification.permission === 'default') {
        window.Notification.requestPermission();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try presetting users preferences for notifications in code:

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Articles/SendingNotifications.html

Answer (score -1):

If you're in Chrome try this:

1. Bring up the menu (it's hidden to the right of the address bar)
2. Click "**Settings**"
3. Click "**Show advanced settings...**"
4. Under "**Privacy**" click "**Content Settings**"
5. Under "**Notifications**" click "**Manage exceptions**"

You can reset the notifications there.